# MySQL: 3 servers on-site architecture

Tags: mysql, percona, high-availability

I have 3 servers with RHEL 6 OS and Percona server running in one of the servers in the same data centre, while the other 2 servers lie idle.

Now I need to implement some kind of on-site redundancy (high-availability) for my databases.

What is the best option we got here? I want to go for Percona cluster but I don't want to since there aren't people who cannot manage the same.

Any other options?

Master and two slaves?
Two Masters (Active-Passive) and One slave?

Need inputs here.

Answer (score 0):

These are your options:

- 1 master with 2 slaves, standard replication. If you have long running or massive transactions you may want to stick with this.
- 1 master with 2 slaves + [MHA](https://code.google.com/p/mysql-master-ha/) to handle failover
- 2 masters (active-passive) with 1 [multi-source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-multi-source.html) [replicating](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/multi-source-replication/) slave. Just to emphasize **active-passive** masters
- 3 node [Percona XtraDB Cluster](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/5.6/index.html)/[MariaDB Galera Cluster](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/what-is-mariadb-galera-cluster/), avoid these if you have long running or big transactions.
- 3 node [PRM cluster](https://github.com/percona/percona-pacemaker-agents/blob/master/doc/PRM-setup-guide.rst)

Others might have a better answer but IMHO these are good options.

Comment: My vote is with PXC.  Any HA you add will require some learning.